# unreal engine 4 c++ | Как сделать cast на blueprint класс

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

В `Unreal engine` есть класс `SkySphere`, он написан на `blueprints` и просто так получить к нему доступ я не могу. Я пробовал через `TSubclassOf` ничо не получилось.

Не могли бы подсказать, как мне объявить переменную в `С++` типа, который написан на `Blueprints`.

Мне просто нужно чтобы я мог `"пипеточкой"` на сцене взять `skysphere`, чтобы из `С++` манипулировать им

Comment: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1730124-access-blueprint-variable-in-c

Comment: @dIm0n нет. Там доступ к переменной blueprint. А мне нужно получить доступ к объекту на сцене(SkySphere)